# "void-variable last-command-char" error when I use semantic to locate symbol

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

Since I use Emacs 24, I always get error when I try to find where a symbol
occurs with `semantic-symref-symbol`. The details are:

1. I push some key to call `semantic-symref-symbol` when the cursor is on
   some symbol of my source file, then I get a list that describes where
   the symbol occurs in `*Symref` buffer.
2. On a entry of the list, I push `SPACE` or `RETURN` key, it jump to the
   right place, but at the same time, Emacs popup `*Backtrace*` buffer in
   other window. Its content is as below:

   ```
   Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable last-command-char)
     semantic-symref-rb-goto-match(#<overlay from 97 to 126 in *Symref stateStack>)
     push-button(97)
     call-interactively(push-button nil nil)
   ```

   Then I follow the `semantic-symref-rb-goto-match` function, which is
   defined in *semantic-symref-list.el*. The elisp function is defined as
   below:

   ```
   (defun semantic-symref-rb-goto-match (&optional button)
     "Go to the file specified in the symref results buffer.
   BUTTON is the button that was clicked."
     (interactive)
     (let* ((tag (button-get button 'tag))
        (line (button-get button 'line))
        (buff (semantic-tag-buffer tag))
        (win (selected-window))
        )
       (switch-to-buffer-other-window buff)
       (goto-line line)
       (pulse-momentary-highlight-one-line (point))
       (when (eq last-command-char ? ) (select-window win))
       )
     )
   ```

   I found the `last-command-char` in the function, but I don't understand
   why Emacs complain that `(void-variable last-command-char)`. It should
   be the key code of `space` or `return`.

I want to know the reason and to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm not getting a bug. Please provide a minimal file for which the bug occurs.

Comment: @abo-abo Each time I use `semantic-symref-symbol`, I got this bug. I do it to a minimal c source file with content of `void main(){}`, I push `C-c r` on `main` to find where `main` occurs, I get a list with only one entry. Then I push SPACE or RETURN key on the only entry of list, the cursor will jump onto the right position, but I'll also get the `*backtrace*` buffer which complains "void-variable last-command-char". According to the answer given by *Drew*, the reason is that the variable `last-command-char` is removed since Emacs 24.3. However, the cedet I use is also built-in in Emacs.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the reference to a `last-command-char` with the `last-command-event`. When it existed, `last-command-char` was an alias for `last-command-event`.

Answer (score 0):

`last-command-char` was removed from Emacs 24.3.  It is still defined in Emacs 24.2.  It is mentioned in the 24.3 NEWS:

```
** Some obsolete functions, variables, and faces have been removed:
*** `last-input-char', `last-command-char', `unread-command-char'
```

In Emacs 24.2, `C-h v last-command-char` says that it has been obsolete since at least Emacs 19.34.

Please report a bug to the owner of the code.

Comment: Yes, I am using Emacs 24.3, the cedet is built-in with emacs. Should I report it as a bug to GNU Emacs? I'll try the newest version of standalone cedet. Thank you, Drew.

Comment: If the calling code is from GNU Emacs, then yes, `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Otherwise, report it to the author of that code.